# unable to select link in second tab in google chrome

Tags: selenium

how to select second link in second tab page in google chrome
browser

```
package Testing;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestPage {
WebDriver driver;
By text = By.linkText("http://www.phptravels.net");
By flights = By.xpath("//a[text()='Flights')]/@herf");


@BeforeTest
public void setup() throws InterruptedException  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://phptravels.com/demo/");
    driver.findElement(text).click();

}

@Test
public void flights() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(flights).click();
}
}
```

> ```
> FAILED: flights
> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
> ```
>
> //a[text()='Flights')]/@herf because of the following error:
>       SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[text()='Flights')]/@herf' is not a valid XPath expression.
>         (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 616 milliseconds
>       For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
>       Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.27.440174
>   (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),
>   userDataDir=C:\Users\SOWJAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4704_3077},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   version=55.0.2883.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
>       Session ID: 30e01d83efbd6b2eecc377a1222de35e
>       *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[text()='Flights')]/@herf}
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:368)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:473)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
>         at Testing.TestPage.flights(TestPage.java:30)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

Answer (score 0):

`XPath` expression in `selenium` should be used to select web-element while your `XPath` is obviously incorrect as it points to attribute (also there is a typo in `@href`... and an extra bracket). You should try following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space(.)='Flights']")).click();
```

Comment: Still i am unable to get the link

Answer (score 0):

Facing `InvalidSelectorException` because your `xpath` is not valid as the way your are using `@href` attribute and an extra ')' bracket

```
By flights = By.xpath("//a[text()='Flights')]/@herf"); // Your xpath
```

Just change your xpath as below and then try -

```
By flights = By.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Flights')]");
```

Comment: Still i am unable to get the second link